# Returning value from MySQL insert function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-insert-id

I have a function, it writes to a mysql database. I can successfully write to the database, but I am having trouble reducing the unique id of the row in the database that it writes to.

And yes I know mysql queries are depreciated soon.

```
function newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest) {
array_walk($newBorrowRequest, 'array_sanitise');

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($newBorrowRequest)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $newBorrowRequest) . '\'';

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `borrowRequest` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
$id = mysql_insert_id(); //this is where the problem is
if (!$query) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}

return $id; //and here
}
```

I call it in another file using this code: ($newBorrowRequest is an array with fields defined).

```
newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest);
```

So essentially my question is: with the above code how can I return the id of the row I am inserting in to? (I don't want to echo it inside the function, it needs to be outside, in the sale file I originally call the function).

Comment: Are you sure the command was successful? Is `$query` `true`? Does `mysql_error()` tell you anything?

Comment: code seems ok.are you getting any error ? what the function is returning ?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Does the table have an auto-increment ID field?

Comment: @deceze yes it successfully inserts into the database. But how can I get the id?

Comment: a) looks like it should work and b) is wide open to SQL injection attacks. If I were you I would construct the query in a string and echo it.

Comment: @TasosBitsios how does it work? How can I return the id, that is the question

Comment: It usually works like that. After inserting with mysql_query you just call mysql_insert_id() and that gives you the last ID. Are you sure that you aren't setting an ID in fields? This will only return auto_increment IDs.

Comment: @TasosBitsios yes - i have a column in the database called ID and it is set as unique, an INT and AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Something is wrong with the statement and the insert is not successful as you think.  Or no auto increment field is set by the insert.  Are the most likely causes.

Comment: try to print the sql before query and paste it here.

Comment: Echo out the "result" of the following after the insert and see if the auto increment field is climbing in value.  "select MAX(id_field) FROM borrowrequest"

Comment: @Gavin he got a sql syntax error, see his comment under Tohir 's answer

Comment: Yes you need to look at your query,  echo it out and share, and someone will be able to help you further.

Answer (score -2):

Simply ***echo newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest);***

It will display the $id. Meanwhile make sure your function page is included on the page you are getting the $id.

include "myfunctionpage.php";
echo newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest);

Comment: The point of the question is that this function is not actually working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.

I get this message: Could not query:Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: Reconcile your database table fields with the fields/columns you are trying to insert inside your code. Check the right spellings of your columns/fields.. That is where u might be getting it wrong